# How to make the do while loop work properly?

Tags: c, loops, do-while

In this code, the second `do while` loop is not working properly. Whenever I press `y` to enter again. It just repeats the `Enter again [y/n]` option again and again instead of starting from 2nd `do-while loop`. I don't want it to give me an option to enter id card number again and again.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    FILE *fr = fopen("file.csv", "r");
    char string[200], toFind[200], opt;
    int err = 0;
    char *line1 = NULL;

    do {
        printf("Enter ID Card number: ");
        scanf("%s", toFind);
        if (strlen(toFind) != 13) {
            break;
        }

        do {     // This loop is not working properly
            {
                err = 1;
                while (fgets(string, 200, fr)) {
                    line1 = strtok(string, "\n");
                    printf("%s\n", line1);
                    err = 0;
                }
            }
            printf("Repeat again [y/n]: ");
            scanf("%s", &opt); 
        } while (opt == 'y');
    } while(err);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: scanf("%s", &opt); - undefined behavour as %s expects the pointer to the char array long enough to accommodate the string

Comment: I didn't understand.

Comment: Then you need to read a C book first https://www.dummies.com/programming/c/basics-of-the-scanf-function-in-c-programming/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first place, you must not use a `%s` directive to read input into a single `char`.  That is for reading non-empty string input, and so it will always store at least *two* characters, the last being a string terminator.  a single `char` does not have space for that, hence your program has undefined behavior.  You could use `%c` instead, but be aware that the latter is among the few field directives that do not cause leading whitespace to be skipped.

> Whenever I press y to enter again. It just repeats the Enter again [y/n] option again and again instead of starting from 2nd do-while loop.

Even if we suppose that overwriting the bounds of of variable `opt` has no observable effect, you are mistaken: when the loop cycles to a new iteration, it starts again at the beginning of the loop body.

But what will it do when it gets there?  Consider that in order to reach the `scanf` in the first place, the program must first have reached and passed through the `while(fgets(string, 200, fr))` loop.  There is no `goto` or `break` in the body of that loop, so it will terminate only when `fgets()` returns a null pointer, indicating that it has reached the end of the file (most likely) or encountered an I/O error.  When control cycles back around to that loop, nothing has changed with file `fr`. It is still positioned at the end of the file (or is still in an error state), so there is every reason to expect that the next `fgets()` will again return a null pointer, so that the body of that loop is not executed even once.

Perhaps you want to `rewind(fr)` before the `fgets()` loop so that you can read through the file again, but the point of that loop is unclear to me, so I'm not sure whether that really makes sense.